# How to get value from input type = number?

Tags: javascript, html, input

**Problem**

So my problem is that I have an `<input type='number'>`, and I'm trying to get the value of the input when the user clicks `enter` and `console.log()` the value. But when I tested, it returned `undefined`.

**Input**

```
<input type="number" value="0" placeholder="Enter Number..." class="insert">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function main() {

        var input = document.getElementsByClassName('insert');

        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
            if(window.event == 13 || e.which == 13) {

                var num = input.value;

                console.log(num)

                /*if(num < 0) {
                    alert('Please enter a positive number');
                }*/

            }
        })

    }

    window.onload = main;
```

Comment: Duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845/4642212).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

know that [**`document.getElementsByClassName(...)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a `HTMLCollection` regardless of whether there is only one element or more.

what you want is this:

```
var num = input[0].value;
```

**note** - typically, if you want to target only one element, you should use an [**`id`**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp) attribute on that element and then use [**`document.getElementById(...)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to retrieve the value of the element.

Comment: Be careful when you say that it returns an `Array`. It returns a `HTMLCollection`, not an array.

Comment: @Marty sure thing, I'll add that. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're selecting the inputs with `getElementsByClassName`. This will return a `HTMLCollection` (essentially an Array).

To avoid this, you can either use `getElementById` or use `input[0].value` which will get the value of the first item in the collection. Given it's a single input, this will work, however not the best approach.

If you have multiple inputs, you would need to loop. For example

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('insert');

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  console.log(inputs[i].value);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

What they said, plus note: you're using `<input type="number">` but when you get that `.value`, it's going to be a string. Your `num < 0` comparison will work, but other operations might produce unwanted results.